# What is the LaTeX command or package that allows one to include command line examples in their document?

Tags: formatting

I am running a command and want to show the output in my document.  I will simply cut and paste it.  I know that the font must be different.  What package or command is used for formatting command output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can try package 'listings'. Serch here for several examples for usage ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Than you both..

Comment: The *listings* package is one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full command and output exactly as rendered (spacing and all) the built-in `verbatim` or [`Verbatim`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) environment might be what you want. Eg.

```
\begin{Verbatim}
$ pdflatex --shell-escape poetrytex.dtx
\end{Verbatim}
```

If you're looking for inline output, just use a monospace font, eg.

```
\texttt{git describe --tags --dirty}
```

Comment: Too limited for my taste. `listings` and `minted` are better.

Comment: What specifically do you want then? It's not clear to me that this is a duplicate (unless you did, in fact, want syntax highlighting, but it's also not clear to me what you want other than just a monospace font.